# Find first n positive columns in each row and create new matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, lapply

I have a 5x5 matrix in R and am wondering how I can select the first 2 positive columns in each row. Say my matrix is:

```
x_mat = matrix(rnorm(25),nrow=5)
```

And looks like this:

```
        [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,]  0.4530790 -0.6345827 -0.09875488 -2.1310380  1.2052932
[2,]  0.8857939  1.7273651 -1.66136354  1.2525782  1.3527161
[3,] -0.2236681  0.2938106  0.45233337  0.4916921  1.0909765
[4,]  1.5959947 -0.9065362 -0.78020171 -1.0510121 0.8550553
[5,]  0.1472118  0.7305333  0.87001933 -2.0218497 -0.7610662
```

How do I select the first two positive columns in each row so that my matrix would look like this:

```
        [,1]       [,2]       
[1,]  0.4530790  1.2052932
[2,]  0.8857939  1.7273651 
[3,]  0.2938106  0.45233337  
[4,]  1.5959947  0.8550553
[5,]  0.1472118  0.7305333
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `apply` to run a function on every row. For each row, select only the positive numbers, then only the first two. Use `t` to transpose to the required format. Note that if there are not two positive values, `NA` will be returned instead.

```
t(apply(x_mat, 1, \(x) x[x > 0][1:2]))
```

> ```
>           [,1]      [,2]
> [1,] 0.9881999        NA
> [2,] 0.1714773        NA
> [3,] 0.7963736 0.5453892
> [4,] 0.5237629 0.0186712
> [5,] 0.2454426 1.4366101
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can order by `row` and `sign` of values in `x_mat`, e.g.,

```
> k <- 3

> m <- matrix(x_mat[order(row(x_mat), -sign(x_mat))], nrow(x_mat), byrow = TRUE)[, 1:k]

> replace(m, m < 0, NA)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 1.2629543 0.7635935        NA
[2,] 0.2522234 0.3773956        NA
[3,] 1.3297993 0.1333364        NA
[4,] 1.2724293 0.4356833 0.8041895
[5,] 0.4146414 2.4046534        NA
```

## Dummy data

```
> set.seed(0)

> (x_mat <- matrix(rnorm(25), nrow = 5))
           [,1]         [,2]       [,3]       [,4]        [,5]
[1,]  1.2629543 -1.539950042  0.7635935 -0.4115108 -0.22426789
[2,] -0.3262334 -0.928567035 -0.7990092  0.2522234  0.37739565
[3,]  1.3297993 -0.294720447 -1.1476570 -0.8919211  0.13333636
[4,]  1.2724293 -0.005767173 -0.2894616  0.4356833  0.80418951
[5,]  0.4146414  2.404653389 -0.2992151 -1.2375384 -0.05710677
```

Comment: Nice! Don't think I have ever used `row` before.